# What should I configure when I put Zend project on windows to Ubuntu Lamp?

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, lamp

What should I configure when I put Zend project on windows to Ubuntu Lamp?
(I asking that beacause my Zend progect not working on Ubuntu, its gives first pages, but after i enter to next page its gives me 404 error(page Not Found), I check if rewrite mod enable with : sudo a2enmod rewrite and get: Module rewrite already enabled  ::: I dont have such probelm on Zend Ce and Wamp servers on Windows).
Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost sounds like the .htaccess file is not being taken into account. As a test you could try route this through index.php manually such as:

http://localhost/controller/action -> http://localhost/index.php/controller/action

This might help to narrow it down.

Comment: Hi,
I right with index.php its works!thank you very much!
What should I change in .htaccess file?

Comment: Have a look where you've defined your virtual host and ensure that you change AllowOverride None to become AllowOverride All. I think that should switch on the .htaccess support for you. If you're using Ubuntu check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your class file names. Windows is a little more forgiving on case-sensitivity issues. It's quite easy to break an application written on a PC and transferred to a LAMP box with the wrong camel-casing on class files. I learned that the hard way.

Comment: Sure. The Zend Autoloader expects class file names to be ucfirst() - e.g. Xml.php. If you create the class file name as XML.php (which I did when I started) the class will work fine on WAMP but will fail (throwing an error) on LAMP. This, of course, assumes you're using the autoloader.